# Unable to extract date of birth from a given format

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have a set of text files from which I have to extract date of birth. The below code is able to extract date of birth from most of the files but is getting failed when given in the below format. May I know how could I extract DOB? The data is very much un-uniform.

Data:

```
data="""
Thomas, John - DOB/Sex:    12/23/1955                                     11/15/2014   11:53 AM"
Jacob's Date of birth is 9/15/1963
Name:Annie; DOB:10/30/1970
```

Code:

```
import re    
pattern = re.compile(r'.*DOB.*((?:\d{1,2})(?:(?:\/|-)\d{1,2})(?(?:\/|-)\d{2,4})).*',re.I)

matches=pattern.findall(data)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

expected output:

```
12/23/1955
```

Comment: Do you have a few more examples of lines from the file? For example, are you going to be seeing something like `d/dd/dd` or is it all `dd/dd/dddd`?

Comment: ya it could be any format not always dd/dd/dddd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re    

data="""
Thomas, John - DOB/Sex:    12/23/1955                                     11/15/2014   11:53 AM"
Jacob's Date of birth is 9/15/1963
Name:Annie; DOB:10/30/1970
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'.*?\b(?:DOB|Date of birth)\b.*?(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-](?:\d\d){1,2})',re.I)

matches=pattern.findall(data)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

**Output:**

```
12/23/1955
9/15/1963
10/30/1970
```

**Explanation:**

```
.*?             : 0 or more anycharacter but newline
\b              : word boundary
(?:             : start non capture group
  DOB           : literally
 |              : OR
  Date of birth : literally
)               : end group
\b              : word boundary
.*?             : 0 or more anycharacter but newline
(               : start group 1
    \d{1,2}     : 1 or 2 digits
    [/-]        : slash or dash
    \d{1,2}     : 1 or 2 digits
    [/-]        : slash or dash
    (?:         : start non capture group
        \d\d    : 2 digits
    ){1,2}      : end group may appear 1 or twice (ie; 2 OR 4 digits)
)               : end capture group 1
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution:
pattern = re.compile(r'.*?\b(?:DOB|Date of birth)\b.*?(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-](?:\d\d){1,2})',re.I)

Comment: @Slickmind: I was not sure you wanted that date. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate. You are very knowledgeable and helpful. Is there a way that I could ask you my future questions on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Slickmind: You're welcome. That is not the way SO works, just ask your question and somebody will answer, if I'm here at this moment, I'll try to answer but there are many people that can give you a good answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
string = "DOB/Sex:    12/23/1955            11/15/2014   11:53 AM"
re.findall(r'.*?DOB.*?:\s+([\d/]+)', string)
```

output:

```
['12/23/1955']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the efforts. It is working fine for the data I have mentioned here. Is it possible to make changes to my code? because the data which I have changes a lot and we cannot use  a particular regex for that

Comment: sure, just extract the regex into a variable. E.g.: `pattern = r'.*?DOB.*?:\s+([\d/]+)' re.findall(pattern, string)`. Then update the pattern whenever the data changes.