# Extracting required names from a given format

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have a  text file containing data as shown below. I have to extract some required names from it. I am trying the below code but not getting the required results.

The file contains data as below:

```
Leader :     Tim Lee ; 34567
Head\Organiser: Sam Mathews; 11:53 am
Head: Alica Mills; 45612
Head\Secretary: Maya Hill; #53190
Captain- Jocey David # 45123
Vice Captain:- Jacob Green;  -65432
```

The code which I am trying:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(Leader|Head\\Organiser|Captain|Vice Captain).*(\w+)',re.I)
matches=pattern.findall(line)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Expected Output:

```
Tim Lee
Sam Mathews
Jocey David
Jacob Green
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
line = '''
Leader :     Tim Lee ; 34567
Head\Organiser: Sam Mathews; 11:53 am
Head: Alica Mills; 45612
Head\Secretary: Maya Hill; #53190
Captain- Jocey David # 45123
Vice Captain:- Jacob Green;  -65432'''
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:Leader|Head(?:\\Organiser|\\Secretary)?|Captain|Vice Captain)\W+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)',re.I)
matches=pattern.findall(line)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 : start non capture group
  Leader            : literally
 |                  : OR
  Head              : literally
  (?:               : start non capture group
    \\Organiser     : literally
   |                : OR
    \\Secretary     : literally
  )?                ! end group, optional
 |                  : OR
  Captain           : literally
 |                  : OR
  Vice Captain      : literally
)                   : end group
\W+                 : 1 or more non word character
(                   : start group 1
  \w+               : 1 or more word char
  (?:               : non capture group
    \s+             : 1 or more spaces
    \w+             : 1 or more word char
  )?                : end group, optional
)                   : end group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Tim Lee
Sam Mathews
Alica Mills
Maya Hill
Jocey David
Jacob Green
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, in the second line, it could be just Head: Sam Mathews; 11:53 am, no 'Organiser', so this code may not work as we are using \W+, is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Sorry for adding some requirements later

Comment: can you please solve my this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887141/unable-to-extract-date-of-birth-from-a-given-format

Comment: This is perfect solution to  my question:
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:Leader|Head(?:\\\w+)?|Captain|Vice Captain)\W+(\w+(?:\s+\w+))',re.I)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
s='''\
Leader :     Tim Lee ; 34567
Head\Organiser: Sam Mathews; 11:53 am
Head: Alica Mills; 45612
Head\Secretary: Maya Hill; #53190
Captain- Jocey David # 45123
Vice Captain:- Jacob Green;  -65432'''
```

You can get the names like so:

```
>>> [e.rstrip() for e in re.findall(r'[:-]+[ \t]+(.*?)[;#]',s)]
['Tim Lee', 'Sam Mathews', 'Alica Mills', 'Maya Hill', 'Jocey David', 'Jacob Green']
```

Or, create a dict of the titles and associated names:

```
>>> {k:v.rstrip() for k,v in re.findall(r'^\s*(Leader|Head\\Organiser|Head|Head\\Secretary|Captain|Vice Captain)\s*[:-]+[ \t]+(.*?)[;#]',s, re.M)}
{'Leader': 'Tim Lee', 'Head\\Organiser': 'Sam Mathews', 'Head': 'Alica Mills', 'Head\\Secretary': 'Maya Hill', 'Captain': 'Jocey David', 'Vice Captain': 'Jacob Green'}
```

Which then can be restricted to the titles desired:

```
>>> {k:v.rstrip() for k,v in re.findall(r'^\s*(Leader|Head\\Organiser|Captain|Vice Captain)\s*[:-]+[ \t]+(.*?)[;#]',s, re.M)}
{'Leader': 'Tim Lee', 'Head\\Organiser': 'Sam Mathews', 'Captain': 'Jocey David', 'Vice Captain': 'Jacob Green'}
```

And if you just want the names (Python 3.6+ maintains the order, so they will be in string order):

```
>>> {k:v.rstrip() for k,v in re.findall(r'^\s*(Leader|Head\\Organiser|Captain|Vice Captain)\s*[:-]+[ \t]+(.*?)[;#]',s, re.M)}.values()
dict_values(['Tim Lee', 'Sam Mathews', 'Jocey David', 'Jacob Green'])
```

[Demo and explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/VVhX7D/1)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is helpful.